# Upgrading an existing model with action_text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activestorage

So after much messing around and WAY *WAY* too many hours troubleshooting getting my app upgraded to 6rc1 (not hard) and webpacker (absolutely miserable and I hate it) operating as intended or at least I think they are, I finally get to install action_text, what I've been working towards implementing.

My scenario:

I have an existing model `general_notes` it looks a little like this

```rb
# general_note.rb model
t.string "general_note_subject"
t.string "general_note_description"
t.bigint "client_id"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.bigint "user_id"
```

My question: 
I want to replace `:general_note_description` with an action_text rich_text_field `:general_note_description`. I essentially just want to replace one for the other, however, I'm not entirely sure if I'm going to have to remove the `general_note_description` from my `general_notes` model first or if it's going to be okay just staying how it is. It worked just staying how it is in a test app but I have no idea if that's going to cause headaches down the road.

The documentation and all the examples I've seen show how to add action_text to a new model not how to upgrade an existing model and implement action_text from there.

Thanks for the help everyone!

I've built a dummy app with similar fields, took the same process of creating an existing model then just adding `has_rich_text :description` to the model and `f.rich_text_area :description` to the view and no errors were flagged but I'm not entirely sure that it won't cause issues down the road. I didn't modify my db beyond the initial creation. I also don't entirely know how exactly action_text is storing those database relationships and if there will be a conflict down the road: `t.string :description` vs `t.reference_to_action_text_rails_magic :description`.

Do things that already exist only go to the original column location and everything created from there on go to the action_text column. Sometimes the rails magic is too obfuscating.